# How can I display a value of NULL where the join did not find any existing values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jira

How can I display a value of NULL where the join did not find any existing values?

```
    SELECT u.display_name Associate
     , ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600)) '30 Days'
     , ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 60 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600)) '60 Days'
     , ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600)) '90 Days'
  FROM worklog w
  JOIN cwd_user u
    ON u.user_name = w.author
  JOIN cwd_membership m
    ON m.directory_id = u.directory_id
   AND m.lower_child_name = u.lower_user_name
 WHERE m.membership_type = 'GROUP_USER'
   AND m.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents'
   AND w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
 GROUP
    BY u. display_name
 ORDER
    BY u.last_name;
```

So on my join `u.user_name = w.author` I want to show all values where there is a `u.user_name`, even if there is not a `w.author`. The `display_name` should still show up, but the values for 40, 60, and 90 days would be NULL. Ideally I want to change the NULL to be 0 instead. Users don't appear in the worklog table unless they have logged work, so right now it only shows two rows for the two people who have. I still want to show everyone that exists in `m.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents'` to know that they have not logged anything.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: do you work with Left Join and IFNULL ?

Comment: Can you set up a rextexter example?

Comment: I tried using Left Joins, but didn't get any results. I am not sure how to use IFNULL, I will look into that.


I am not familiar with a rextexter. I will set up an example if you can tell me how.



I am new to this, so my apologies.

Comment: @Cole, I was new to this as well a couple of days ago; just go to rexter.com, choose your language (MySql), write the scripts and get a permanent link.

Comment: It doesn't run on there, but here are the links.

Original query: http://rextester.com/PCG17440

Updated query (still not working how I want): http://rextester.com/MKKYI38031

Comment: You need to create your tables and add some sample data as well. Or you can edit your original post and add the scripts and sample data (insert statements) there.

Comment: See LEFT JOIN..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`, but you need to be careful about all the joins and the `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT u.display_name  as Associate,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600)) as `30 Days`,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 60 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600)) as `60 Days`,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY THEN w.timeworked END/3600)) as `90 Days`
FROM cwd_user u JOIN -- Not sure if this should be LEFT JOIN or not
     cwd_membership m
     ON m.directory_id = u.directory_id AND
        m.lower_child_name = u.lower_user_name AND
        m.membership_type = 'GROUP_USER' AND
        m.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents' LEFT JOIN
     worklog w 
     ON u.user_name = w.author AND
        w.startdate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
GROUP BY u. display_name
ORDER BY u.last_name;
```

I'm not sure if the join to `m` should be an inner join or left join.  It depends on whether you want filtering based on that table as well.

Comment: That works if I use a normal join for m and take out the AND before LEFT JOIN on w. Thank you!